# Return object from array map inside a for loop JS

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping, scrape

I'm trying to return an object from an array map inside a for loop and push it to productsData array but I'm getting [ [Object], [Object] ]. The array in question is 'lol'. Here's the code below:

```
for (let i = 0; i < productsUrls.length; i++) {
        let ficheTechnique = [];
        let request = await axios.get(productsUrls[i]);
        const $ = cheerio.load(request.data);
        let productUrl = productsUrls[i];
        let title = $('div.col10').find('h1.-fs20.-pts.-pbxs').text();
        let price = $('div.-phs').find('div span.-b.-ltr.-tal.-fs24').text();
        let description = $('div.card.aim.-mtm').find('div.markup.-mhm.-pvl.-oxa.-sc').text();
        let descriptionImg = $('div.card.aim.-mtm').find('div.markup.-mhm.-pvl.-oxa.-sc center img').attr('data-src');
        let lol = $('.row.-pas article').map((i, el) => {
            let h2 = $(el).find('h2.hdr.-upp.-fs14.-m.-pam').text();
            let characteristiques = $(el).find('.markup.-pam').text() || $(el).find('.-pvs.-mvxs.-phm.-lsn').text();
            return {
                h2,
                characteristiques
            };
        }).get();
        console.log('ficheTechnique', lol);
        productsData.push({
            productUrl,
            title,
            // price,
            // description,
            // descriptionImg,
            // ficheTechnique,
            lol
        })
    }
```

Comment: try to use console.dir or console.table

Comment: Doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your `map` call is returning an array of objects, each containing `h2` and `characteristiques` attributes.

Comment: Yes, but they are undefined.

Comment: Honestly, other than spamming console.log, I notice that you are using the `i` variable both at the beginning of the for loop and at the declaration of the `map` call. Check to see if that part of the logic is working correctly.